# AWS Glue Crawler - how to get proper data types

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a Glue Crawler that reads data from S3 and auto-assign data types.

Data type for a first column should be Number (Integer) but it is showing as Decimal (38,10).
Here is how Athena is showing data for first 10 records (after Glue Crawler ran):

```
1   3568813.0000000000
2   3568814.0000000000
3   3570809.0000000000
4   3570810.0000000000
5   3573970.0000000000
6   3573971.0000000000
7   3573972.0000000000
8   3573973.0000000000
9   3573974.0000000000
10  3573975.0000000000
```

(ideally - we should see clean numbers without trailing zeros..)

Is there a way to 'force' a proper Data Type inferring with Glue Crawler? If not - how can this be fixed after the crawling operation?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to manually change that, i.e do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and execute its result within Athena but with  manually changed data type?)

Comment: could you post an example of the input data? is it CSV, Parquet, JSON?